# Select2 Multiple de Bootstrap no se cierra

Tags: jquery, html5, bootstrap

tengo este problema con el select2 de bootstrap (3.3.7) Es un select multiple que no se cierra. Se supone que al dar click fuera del select, el dropdown que contiene la lista de opciones debe cerrarse y no lo hace.
Estoy usando el navegador Explorer versión 11, lo raro es que en Firefox funciona perfectamente. ¿Alguna idea de lo que puede ser?

Aqui les dejo el select en html

```js
$(".select2").select2();
```

```html
<select name="selectUser[]" id="selectUser" class="form-control select2" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Select a User"  style="width: 100%;">
     <option>Delaware</option>
     <option>Tennessee</option>
     <option>Texas</option>
     <option>Washington</option>
</select>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Primero debes encontrar el error que arroja el js de select2
Corre tu página y abres el inspect element y en la barra de errrores busca el ultimo y postealo para empezar a rastrear el error, ya que ese plugin tiene soporte en todos los navegadores.

Comment: Ya lo he hecho, no arroja ningún error.

Comment: Entonces yo buscaría en cuestión de estilos